# python api json dict in dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, api, python-requests

I want to scrape data at the county level from https://apidocs.covidactnow.org

However I could only get a dataframe with one line for each county, and data for each date is stored within a dictionary in each row/county. I would like to access this data and store it in long format (= have one row per county-date).

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir('/home/username/Desktop/')

    url = 'https://api.covidactnow.org/v2/counties.timeseries.json?apiKey=ENTER_YOUR_KEY'
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    
    data = pd.DataFrame(response)
```

This seems like a trivial question, but I've tried for hours. What would be the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.covidactnow.org/v2/states.timeseries.csv?apiKey=YOURAPIKEY'

response = requests.get(url)
csv_response = (response.text)

# Then you can transform STRING to CSV
```

Check this fo string to CSV --> [python parsing string to csv format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870495/python-parsing-string-to-csv-format/55870736)